# How to get checkout session data with cacheable true in block in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, block-cache

I want to get Checkout session data with cacheable="true" in the block. Actually, I want to update the cart count in the header after add to cart (add to cart on refresh) which is not updating. With cacheable="false" it works perfectly but with cacheable="true" it does not work.

Comment: which data you want?

Comment: I want to get updated data from the checkout session e.g quote item counts